# getHours(), show and hide

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on my first website and have run into an issue that I just can't pass. I am using JavaScript to show and hide elements in my HTML (sounds easy enough right?) But it's not working the way it should. Even when I have an alert on the page that shows the number returned by variable 'hours', there is some issue when showing the correct information.

```
var today = new Date();
var hours = today.getHours();

alert(hours)

let day = document.querySelector('.day')
let night = document.querySelector('.night')

if (hours > 9 || hours < 12) {
    day.style.display = "block";
    night.style.display = "none";
}

else {
    day.style.display = "none";
    night.style.display = "block";
    
    let blurred = document.querySelector('h1')
    blurred.classList.add('blur');
}
```

Not to mention that eventually it should work with getUTCHours, however thought I would try this way first.

Comment: What is the issue you get? What do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: `hours > 9 || hours < 12` is _always_ true. An hour is always either after 9, _OR_ before 12. You need `&&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you specified a wrong `if` statement since an hour is *always* greater than 9 *or* less than 12.

Probably you meant something like `if (hours >= 9 && hours <= 12)`?